# Trying to log rows as unique or copy by ID column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script for a google sheet to log whether or not an ID column contains repeated or unique ID numbers.

This is what I have so far:

```
function mergeCellValuesVert() {
  
  var spreadsheetId = '1GCJw9mwgi0n84iZ8L4MntBioM5Y1YtxhJ4zatNY1kZw';
  var rangeName = 'Sheet1!A2:H';
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
  
  if (!values){
    
    return;
    
  }
  else {
    
    for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row ++){
      
      var col = 0;
      
      if(values[row][col] == values[row-1][col]){
        Logger.log('Copy');
        }
      else {
        Logger.log('Unique');
      }
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 18, file "Code")"

I can avoid the error by removing the [col] but then the code will access the whole row instead of just the first cell.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes and I really advice you to take a look at the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Nevertheless, the error you are getting is located at the second if statement of your code. You are trying to access this: `values[row-1][col]`. However, `row` starts from 0 and therefore this `values[-1][col]` will generate an error. I assume you want to start from `row=1` but this is just a speculation.

Try this:

```
function mergeCellValuesVert() {
  
  var spreadsheetId = '1GCJw9mwgi0n84iZ8L4MntBioM5Y1YtxhJ4zatNY1kZw';
  var rangeName = 'A2:H';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  var values = sheet.getRange(rangeName).getValues();
  
  if (!values){
    
    return;
    
  }
  else {
    
    for (var row = 1; row < values.length; row ++){
      
      var col = 0;
      
      if(values[row][col] == values[row-1][col]){
        Logger.log('Copy');
        }
      else {
        Logger.log('Unique');
      }
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it fails on the first iteration. On the first pass through, `row = 0` and `col = 0`, so on this line:

```
if(values[row][col] == values[row-1][col]){
```

you are doing this:

```
if(values[0][0] == values[-1][0]) { ... }
```

`values[-1]` is returning undefined, which is why you're getting an error. If you want to check each row sequentially, I'd recommend initializing row to 1 like so:

```
for (var row = 1; row < values.length; row ++){
```

This way you're starting at the second row and can check the previous column without getting `undefined`.